# local user on samba server machine using it's primary group even though force group is used

Tags: permissions, users, samba, group

So I'm trying to set up a password protected samba share with permissions. And I believe I have set everything up decently correctly and the samba share works as intended.

But I'm having a slight problem regarding a local user accessing and using the same directory as the share. Anything the user creates will have it's primary group (another group than file-server-admin) as the owner of it and it'll be uneditable by any other users on the samba share even though force group is used. I understand that this is probably the intended way it's supposed to work but is there anyway to force group usage of a certain user inside a certain directory of a linux system or will I have to change the primary group of that user? Or is there any other solution?

I am using ubuntu server 20.04 if that will help

And this is the config for my samba share

```
[Aether]
  comment = file-server-share
  path = /mnt/omega
  valid users = @file-server-admin
  browsable = yes
  writable = yes
  read only = no
  force group = file-server-admin
  create mask = 0664
  force create mode = 0664
  directory mask = 0774
  force directory mask = 0774
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with force user additionally?

> If the force user parameter is also set the group specified in force group will override the primary group set in force user.

EDIT: Maybe this will help https://serverfault.com/a/445096/853288

Comment: Functionality wise this does seem to work, but now any file or directory created by any user will have the user owner of the force user specified, and I lose the information of who created the file. Also I think it won't work if another user on the local machine creates anything on the share, so I think I'm looking for a more robust solution

Comment: Hmm.. can you set persmissions via the _Windows_ GUI on the Share? There was an ACL with CREATOR_GROUP to force that behaviour. - Probabbly also via setfacl. But you have to know what to do :-)